# Can numerical solvers solve a constraint if there are also certain variables in it that are integers?

Tags: integer, numerical-methods, solver

I believe the implicit assumption is that all variables are reals.

More formally, can numerical solvers handle quantifier-free non-linear (mixed) integer real constraints (undecidable), or some classes of such constraints efficiently? Any pointers would be very helpful.

Comment: MINLP (Mixed Integer Nonlinear Programming) solvers are readily available. Some of them you can try out at [NEOS](https://neos-server.org/neos/).

Comment: Looks interesting, thanks! Will look at that.